# native module compile error on ubuntu for node-webcrypto-ossl on electron project

Tags: node.js, electron

I am trying to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-webcrypto-ossl this module in an electron project.

When I try to build it gives me following error.

*g++: error: /home/username/.electron-gyp/.node-gyp/4.0.0/deps/openssl/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a: No such file or directory
nodessl.target.mk:167: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/nodessl.node' failed*

This module works ok in node only project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the openssl dependency is missing, were dependencies installed?

Comment: Fixed it by passing proper openssl directory in .npmrc